# What is the Oblivion-symbol gauntlet in the Midden?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Below the College of Magic in Winterhold, there is some type of black daedric-looking gauntlet (with an Oblivion sign in the palm) on a pedestal.  You cannot pick it up.

Can anyone tell me what this is for, and how to activate it?

Answer (score 6):

If, while facing the "palm" of the gauntlet, you look to your right, you'll see a table with a journal and a key on it. The journal will mention a summoning ritual, and four rings that were taken from the gauntlet, and which are now stored in the Arcaneum.

On the floor around the outer ring, there's a chest called the "Investigator's Chest;" the key from the table by the journal will open this chest, and you'll find the four rings. Go back down to the Midden and use trial-and-error to get the rings on the right fingers - each ring will only go on one finger, so this takes very little time. Be prepared for a bit of a fight, as using the gauntlet summons a rather beastly fellow. I'm not sure if you HAVE to fight him or not, but I did, and he wasn't too bad.

Comment: A fight as in high level or should I prepare immensely?

Comment: It's nothing hugely challenging; if you fought your way all the way up to Winterhold you're probably more than prepared for it. I zapped the fellow who spawned a few times and that was it, really.

Comment: The Investigator's chest is in the arcaneum. See http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Midden

Comment: @Artless If you don't kill him you get treasure