# How do I activate the Daedric gauntlet in the Midden?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Oblivion-symbol gauntlet in the Midden?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/what-is-the-oblivion-symbol-gauntlet-in-the-midden)

What is the purpose of Daedric gauntlet in the Midden, and why can't I activate it? Are there fail conditions that can prevent one from activating it? If not, what do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This questions has already been asked.  You can use the search bar in the upper right to find previously asked questions.  Please read our [FAQ] for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [sites guide](http://supremegamer.hubpages.com/hub/skyrim-midden-daedric-relic-puzzle) on this puzzle. It is part of a quest where you interact with [Velehk Sain](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Velehk_Sain). [UESP's Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Midden) on The Midden explains how to activate it:

```
The Midden Dark contains a ritual chamber with a 
large black metal gauntlet on a 
pedestal. The symbol of Oblivion is emblazened on the palm of the gauntlet.
The Midden Incident Report can be found on the table here,
along with the Investigator's Key. 
Following the clues in the report, 
the player can find the needed rings in the Arcanaeum,
in a master-locked chest. The lock can be picked,
or simply opened with the key. 
Returning the rings to the gauntlet will activate it,
and the gauntlet will clench into a fist. 
Shortly afterwards the dremora Velehk Sain will be summoned.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What If I may or may not have accidently stole these rings earleir in the game and lost them?

Comment: Pretty sure they're flagged as quest items, and you shouldn't have been able to get rid of them by any other means.

Comment: Yes, I am PRETTY sure that it is a misc quest. Haven't done it myself but hope to

Comment: So does that mean I completely failed?

Comment: No because you cant get rid of the rings

Comment: But their not in my inventory I might have given them to one of my old companions but I wouldnt have a clue where to find them

Comment: Yeah I looked their just before in a chest called investigators  chest but there's nothing in their because I was stupid enough to steal and lose them DX I probably got them taken of me when I was put in a jail

Comment: I also can't find the conjureation guy at winter hold to activate the pedestal in the midden

Comment: DX I failed an easy quest

Comment: @Thedeadricwarrior Are you on Xbox, PS3, or PC?

Comment: @Thedeadricwarrior You could look through the evidence chests in all of the holds:/

Comment: I did and they aren't there

Comment: What device are you playing on

Comment: Xbox 360 so I can't use console Xbox 360 :(

Comment: @deadric warrior there is a way, ill find the link later